# JavaScript - Store multiple objects in array and access their properties via

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

So here I have a database of user objects and I would like to push each one into the 'allUsers' array. I then want to be able to loop through this array and access a property e.g. `allUsers[i].genrePref`. How do I push all of these variables into the array to store them like `[user, jon, lucy, mike, luke...`

```
    // Users
    var user = {username: user9110252username, genrePref: user9110252genre};
    var jon = {username: 'Jon', genrePref: 'rock'};
    var lucy = {username: 'Lucy', genrePref: 'pop'};
    var mike = {username: 'Mike', genrePref: 'rock'};
    var luke = {username: 'Luke', genrePref: 'house'};
    var james = {username: 'James', genrePref: 'house'};
    var dave = {username: 'Dave', genrePref: 'bass'};
    var sarah = {username: 'Sarah', genrePref: 'country'};
    var natalie = {username: 'Natalie', genrePref: 'bass'};


    // Users array
    var allUsers = [];
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To just add the *variables* to the array, there's really no other way except to do exactly what you did in your example, which is to manually add each variable to your array.

```
// Users array
var allUsers = [
    user,
    jon,
    lucy,
    mike,
    luke,
    james,
    dave,
    sarah,
    natalie
];
```

BUT, you could probably do something a little more robust, which in its simplest form is to define an object literal called `users` that contains each user object. Then you not only have the added benefit of a pseudo-namespacing around your users, you can easily iterate over the object literal and put each user into an array, as such:

```
// Users
var users = {
    user : {username: user9110252username, genrePref: user9110252genre},
    jon : {username: 'Jon', genrePref: 'rock'},
    lucy : {username: 'Lucy', genrePref: 'pop'},
    mike : {username: 'Mike', genrePref: 'rock'},
    luke : {username: 'Luke', genrePref: 'house'},
    james : {username: 'James', genrePref: 'house'},
    dave : {username: 'Dave', genrePref: 'bass'},
    sarah : {username: 'Sarah', genrePref: 'country'},
    natalie : {username: 'Natalie', genrePref: 'bass'}
}

// Users array
var allUsers = [];

// Populate users array
for(var key in users) {
    allUsers.push(users[key]);
}
```

One last note on style. You should probably avoid explicitly setting the 'key' of each user object in your `users` object literal to be the *name* of the user. If you have any users with the same name, this model will break. Instead, consider generating some kind of unique key, like a guid, or some other unique value for each user. That way you'll never accidentally overwrite an entry in your `users` object if, for example, you are populating this `users` object from some database and two or more users happen to have the same name.

Good luck.

Comment: I probably should have worded my question a bit better but what you have just given me is exactly what I wanted to do! Thank you!

Comment: no problem. don't forget to mark as correct. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/cewuwo/2/edit?js,console)

Just use `.push` to push all of them in like so:

```
var allUsers = [];

allUsers.push(allUsers, user, jon, lucy, mike, luke, james, dave, sarah, natalie);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  var arr = [{username: 'Jon', genrePref: 'rock'},{username: 'Lucy', genrePref: 'pop'},{username: 'Mike', genrePref: 'rock'},{username: 'Luke', genrePref: 'house'},{username: 'James', genrePref: 'house'},{username: 'Dave', genrePref: 'bass'},{username: 'Sarah', genrePref: 'country'},{username: 'Natalie', genrePref: 'bass'}];
 
 var text = "<table border ='1'><tr><th>Username</th><th>genrePref</th></tr>"
 for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     text+="<tr><td>"+arr[i].username+"</td><td>"+arr[i].genrePref+"</td></tr>"    
 }
 text+="</table>";
    document.write(text);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
     var arr = [{username: 'Jon', genrePref: 'rock'},{username: 'Lucy', genrePref: 'pop'},{username: 'Mike', genrePref: 'rock'},{username: 'Luke', genrePref: 'house'},{username: 'James', genrePref: 'house'},{username: 'Dave', genrePref: 'bass'},{username: 'Sarah', genrePref: 'country'},{username: 'Natalie', genrePref: 'bass'}];
    
    var text = "<table border ='1'><tr><th>Username</th><th>genrePref</th></tr>"
    for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     text+="<tr><td>"+arr[i].username+"</td><td>"+arr[i].genrePref+"</td></tr>"             
    }
    text+="</table>";
    document.write(text);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```